# Docker with Node Does Not Run npm commands

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I've created a docker container with `node:lts` (or any other Node container) in it. It works without problem on my development machine however when I move the image to another machine (both Windows with WSL installed) my NPM commands don't run. It only echoes the command.

[image]

I tried to install Node in a standalone container, and install the container on the other machine, nothing worked. My current `start` command in the `package.json` is

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cgb-scripts start"
},
```

I tried to add `node index.js` command to the start, the result is the same however I can run the same command using the bash.

Why does this happen?

My current `docker-compose.yml` file is

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ../db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 33060:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: demo
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: demo
    networks:
      - wpdevsite

  nodejs:
    container_name: wp_nodejs
    image: node:lts
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ../wp:/app
    networks:
      - wpdevsite

networks:
  wpdevsite:
```

Comment: You say you move the 'image' over to the new machine. You seem to use unmodfied images from docker hub, so that's confusing. Do you mean that you move your docker-compose file to the other machine? If so, you also need to move the `db` and `wp` directories across, since you mount those into your containers.

Comment: Yes, sorry, at first I moved the image, seen the issue then changed it to the default docker image, still seeing the issue. The `db` folder is empty right now and `wp` folder only includes the script.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the commands you issue to access the container and the commands you run inside it? Usually the goal is to have the script start automatically when you run `docker-compose` but you don't do/want that, right?

Comment: That's right. Right now, I don't want a script start automatically. I run

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
# cd /app/
# npm start
```